# Does an ASIC have an instruction set?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ethernet, asic, mac, instruction-set

Does an Application Specific Integrated Circuit have an instruction set like a CPU?

If yes, then that would contradict the statement "ASIC is faster than CPU" because having an instruction set means it is performing operations sequentially instead of parallel. Therefore it would have no difference from a CPU.

If no, then how could a CPU communicate with an ASIC? For example, consider a managed ethernet switch. This switch, like any other switch, is said to implement MAC bridging (switching) "on hardware", which basically means "using an ASIC". But this switch is a managed switch, and we can do some configurations like setting VLANs for example. And such features like VLAN configuration, if I am not mistaken, is implemented on software (using CPU). So if for example you are setting VLAN, then how would the CPU tell the ASIC that "this port belongs to this VLAN" or "broadcast this packet only to these ports", etc., if it has no instruction set?

Comment: "ASIC" is a general term, so it's almost impossible to compare them from general sense. An ASIC can implement many different architectures, depending on the design: parallel logic, cpu, memory buffers, etc. An ASCI doesn't necessarily have a CPU implemented in its logic or a concept of an instruction set, but it could. "ASIC is faster than a CPU" depends on the ASIC, depends on the CPU, and depends on how you're measuring "faster". How a CPU interacts with an ASIC is dependent on the ASIC, and how it implements a VLAN (if that's what it does) is dependent on the ASIC.

Comment: This question is essentially asking for tuition/discussion on the very basics of custom digital logic (ASICS, FPGAs etc.). It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. VTC for those reasons. You'll find mountains of information explaining what ASICs, FPGAs etc. are and how they work, already written for beginners in tremendous detail and freely available on the internet for you to research and learn from. Hope you can see that.

Comment: Any general-purpose CPU, even with advanced instructions (MMX, SIMD, SSE etc.) will *always* be slower than custom-designed hardware for *some* task.  And in the case of a managed network switch, the manufacturer can afford millions of dollars to design an ultra-high-performance ASIC for just *that* task.  So the ASIC very well could have some registers and settings, perhaps even SPI or I2C, even a "soft-core"... whatever the designer wants or needs.  And of course, this ASIC would be *terrible* at general-purpose computing, if it could even do that at all.

Comment: I think that rather than trying to answer the question as stated I'm going to suggest -- go study the difference between electronic logic circuits ("logic") and processors; specifically how logic can be _used_ to build either a general-purpose CPU or for some specific task (such as a switch).  Then understand that a digital ASIC is just a bunch of logic that a designer can put together -- and that typically an ASIC will have at least one CPU, and a whole lot of logic aimed at a specific task.

Comment: A CPU is subset of ASIC. You should go back to fundamentals.

Comment: If you want it to, then it does! An ASIC does literally whatever you want. That's the AS part. (But you have to spend millions of dollars to make it do that)

Comment: I think what you are actually asking is *how can a CPU control a peripheral device?* - your real question applies to everything from Ethernet switches to mice and keyboards or joysticks with rumble motors or USB missile launchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is going to sound like a reductive statement, but the control is done in an application-specific way, so a generic answer is hard to write here. Instead, I'll give some basic background and then provide an example.

A *configurable* ASIC<sup>1</sup> is going to have some kind of control interface, whether something slow like SPI or I2C, or perhaps something fast like PCIe or AXI so it can join a system's memory bus. Over that control interface, a CPU can provide instructions, that the ASIC will handle in some application-specific manner.  I'll give an example for a *plausible* approach to make a network switch ASIC, because that's the example you used.

Your layer-2 network switch ASIC might have some registers (in the digital electronics, rather than CPU-specific sense) associated with each of its input ports, controlling things such as whether the port is up, the VLAN number, etc. Each of the ports has its own control registers (likely physically close to rest of the port's hardware on the chip floorplan), so the ports can handle packets at the same time. **These registers are probably the closest to an "instruction set" for your ASIC, and even then they're configuration bits, rather than sequential CPU instructions.**

The ASIC is also designed so that these registers can be controlled via the control interface (i.e. by including appropriate logic that routes appropriate data and activates the write-enable when the control interface receives a suitable write). When the main CPU wants to reconfigure any given port, it'll write to these registers through the control interface. In the case where the ASIC is on the memory bus, it'll be mapped to some region of the address map, and the CPU will issue writes to those addresses - instead of going to RAM, the ASIC's control interface itself's address decoder will detect these writes and act upon them.

<sup>1</sup> An ASIC may not be configurable at all. Cheap switches might be built on cheap switch ASICs that don't even have the concept of VLAN tagging or other fancy features - as long as they're powered they'll just blindly forward frames.